# How to hyperlink an image in plotly-dash?

Tags: python, html, plotly-dash

From reviewing the dash documentation, I cannot see any syntax or examples for nesting a hyperlink within an image. I am essentially trying to achieve the following but in a dash layout friendly format (regardless of whether it uses html or dash-core-components):

```
<a href="https://www.twitter.com/username">
    <img alt="Link to my twitter" src="twitterlogo.png"
    width=32" height="32">
</a>
```

Appreciate any help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this will work:

```py
html.A(
    href="https://www.twitter.com/username",
    children=[
        html.Img(
            alt="Link to my twitter",
            src="twitterlogo.png",
        )
    ]
)
```

Comment: what if I want to take  2 user inputs in the form of integers and display the corresponding image? like if input is 1,2 then the images displayed are 1.png and 2.png

Comment: You can use a callback to update the `children` component for that.